# How to convert byte array to union struct by one operation?

Tags: c#, struct, type-conversion, byte, union

I declared in C# something like union in C++:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit, Size = 5)]
public struct Marker
{
        [FieldOffset(0)] public byte label;
        [FieldOffset(1)] public int count;

        [FieldOffset(1)] private byte count_0;
        [FieldOffset(2)] private byte count_1;
        [FieldOffset(3)] private byte count_2;
        [FieldOffset(4)] private byte count_3;
}
```

Also I have `byte[] bytes` with size 5. I need to convert my array to Marker object. I can do it by following way:

```
var marker = new Marker 
{
    label = bytes[0],
    count = BitConverter.ToInt32(bytes, 1)
}
```

Or:

```
var marker = new Marker 
{
    label = bytes[0],
    count_0 = bytes[1],
    count_1 = bytes[2],
    count_2 = bytes[3],
    count_3 = bytes[4]
}
```

That's OK, but I think it is possible to do by more optimal way from performance view - just point `marker` to first byte of `bytes`. I trying to find something like this:

```
BitConverter.To<Marker>(bytes);
```

How to convert byte array to union struct by one operation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //Creating test data
        List<byte> data = new List<byte>();
        data.Add(123);
        data.AddRange(BitConverter.GetBytes((int)123456));

        //Converting test data to Struct
        Marker m = StructFromBytes<Marker>(data.ToArray());

        //Check if it works
        Console.WriteLine(m.label); //Prints 123
        Console.WriteLine(m.count); //Prints 123456
    }

    private static T StructFromBytes<T>(byte[] bytes)
    {
        int structSize = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(T));
        byte[] structBytes = new byte[structSize];
        Array.Copy(bytes, 0, structBytes, 0, structSize);

        GCHandle handle = GCHandle.Alloc(structBytes, GCHandleType.Pinned);
        T theStructure = (T)Marshal.PtrToStructure(handle.AddrOfPinnedObject(), typeof(T));
        handle.Free();

        return theStructure;
    }
```

Comment: If performance is your problem, that will be counter-productive. Pinning your data and marshalling it should be _way_ more time consuming than just assigning the values.

Comment: He says in the question that he wants optimal performance. Interop wouldn't be the way to go...

Comment: I agree and that is why I upvoted your answer.
But the OP also wants to do it the easy way and using `StructFromBytes<Marker>(bytes)` is easier than creating a constructor for every struct.

Comment: That's right, if you have lots of different structs, your way is flexible enough to handle all of them. It just depends what your aim is.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a constructor:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit, Size = 5)]
public struct Marker
{
    [FieldOffset(0)] public byte label;
    [FieldOffset(1)] public int count;

    [FieldOffset(1)] private byte count_0;
    [FieldOffset(2)] private byte count_1;
    [FieldOffset(3)] private byte count_2;
    [FieldOffset(4)] private byte count_3;

    public Marker(byte[] bytes)
    {
       label = bytes[0];
       count_0 = bytes[1];
       count_1 = bytes[2];
       count_2 = bytes[3];
       count_3 = bytes[4];
    }
}
```

Or an operator overload:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit, Size = 5)]
public struct Marker
{
    [FieldOffset(0)] public byte label;
    [FieldOffset(1)] public int count;

    [FieldOffset(1)] private byte count_0;
    [FieldOffset(2)] private byte count_1;
    [FieldOffset(3)] private byte count_2;
    [FieldOffset(4)] private byte count_3;

    public static explicit operator Marker(byte[] bytes)
    {
       Marker result = new Marker();
       result.label = bytes[0];
       result.count_0 = bytes[1];
       result.count_1 = bytes[2];
       result.count_2 = bytes[3];
       result.count_3 = bytes[4];
       return result;
    }
}
```

Both solutions would make creating your struct a one-liner:

```
Marker marker = new Marker(bytes);
Marker marker = (Marker)bytes;
```

Comment: This is the same. For every `result.count_'x' = bytes['y']` will be used one Int32 or Int64 processor command.

Comment: Why would you care? Are you so thight on performance that it matters to you? If you want to optimize performance, run a profiler. That will be a better use of your time than worrying about CPU commands.

Comment: I used `struct` and `FieldOffset` for bytes mapping - of course this question about performance. I do not need to use profiler I see performance problem (in my real task it is critical) and I am trying to find solution. I edited my question for make more clear.

Comment: By far the most gains in performance can be done by revising the design of the system. When it comes down to the point that a marginal change in the number of CPU commands makes the difference, C# is the wrong language. You'll have to use assembly language in order to influence performance on CPU command level.

Comment: didn't know you can also create your own cast +1 for you